# ARM64 assembly - execve arguments on stack

Tags: assembly, stack, arm64, shellcode, execve

I am new to Aarch64 assembly (but I know some basics of x86 assembly). I am trying to write something like a "shellcode" on Android OS.

This shellcode is injected into another function. It is supposed to create a file `/data/local/tmp/AAABBBCCC` using `execve` and `/system/bin/sh -c`. I don't have to care about null bytes in my case.

Prior to `execve` call I make a syscall `open_at` (with `O_CREAT` and `O_EXCL`) and create another file in `/data/local/tmp/` (I load the address of the filename using `adr x1, path`).

```
...

call to open_at

... 

// push terminating 0
mov     x1, 0
str     x1, [sp, #-16]!
// push arg2
adr     x1, arg2
str     x1, [sp, #-16]!
// push arg1
adr     x1, arg1
str     x1, [sp, #-16]!
// push arg0
adr     x1, arg0
str     x1, [sp, #-16]!
// call execve
adr     x0, command
ldr     x1, [sp]
mov     x2, 0
mov     x8, SYS_EXECVE
svc     0

...
.balign 4
command:
    .string "/system/bin/sh"
arg0:
    .string "/system/bin/sh"
arg1:
    .string "-c"
arg2:
    .string "/system/bin/touch /data/local/tmp/AAABBCCC"
```

I know that for x86 you need to get the address of the first string using a trick with `CALL` instruction in order to make the argument array on the stack, because if you use labels like I did here, the addresses of the labels are contained within the instruction opcodes and after the injection they're not valid. But this should be a different case, right? The instruction `ADR` should be pc-relative and in its opcode I don't see any addresses, just relative distances.

When I inject the code to the funtion, the call to `open_at` always succeeds and the file is created. However the file that should be created by `execve` is never created.

What is the right way to make the argument array on the stack for `execve` on Aarch64? The stack must be 16-aligned, so I tried to always push two arguments at a time (using `STP`), but that did not work either.

The code for injecting is made using `aarch64-linux-android` toolchain like this:

```
as -o code.o code.asm
objcopy -O binary code.bin code.o
xxd -i code.bin
```

Thank you for your answers!

Comment: Have you tried using `strace` to understand what system calls your code performs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a few minutes after I posted this question I realized where the mistake was.

The correct way to create the array of arguments on the stack is using the STP instruction. It stores two registers at a time (I was using it wrong before -- I provided the registers in a wrong order). It should be done like this:

```
mov     x1, 0
adr     x2, arg2
stp     x2, x1, [sp, #-16]!

adr     x1, arg1
adr     x2, arg0
stp     x2, x1, [sp, #-16]!
```

Comment: Or you could have used `[sp, #-8]!` to push one value at a time instead of storing 8 bytes and decrementing SP by 16.  But yes, `stp` is clearly better, because it's fast and saves total instructions.

Comment: Really? If you look at this [website](https://community.arm.com/processors/b/blog/posts/using-the-stack-in-aarch64-implementing-push-and-pop), the first code listing under "The Problem" headline that starts with `Broken AArch64 implementation of ...` says it wouldn't work...

Comment: Ah thanks, I don't know AArch64 very well; thanks for the link.  I didn't know about 16-byte stack alignment being required at all times, and enforced by hardware!  (Apparently can be disabled by privileged code, though: https://community.arm.com/processors/b/blog/posts/using-the-stack-in-aarch32-and-aarch64)  That's an interesting feature; I wonder why exactly they did that instead of leaving it up to calling conventions to require / guarantee stack alignment like on x86 and other ISAs.